# Windows Updates are not installed when I restart my machine

Tags: windows, updates

The following is displayed in Windows Settings:

[image]

but when I restart my machine nothing changes.

When I press "Check for updates" no new updates appear.

Comment: Are you connected to an Active Directory domain?

Comment: @Ramhound no I am not.  But I set “Configure Automatic Updates” and “No auto-restart for scheduled Automatic Update installation” to Enable in `Local Computer Policy->Computer Configuration->Administrative Templates->Windows Components->Windows Update` and this worked until today.

Comment: If you disable those policies are you able to receive updates?

Comment: In addition to @Ramhound's suggestion also run the Microsoft Update Troubleshooter.   .....  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-update-troubleshooter-19bc41ca-ad72-ae67-af3c-89ce169755dd

Comment: Try to update via the [Windows Update Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).

Comment: @Ramhound If I disable these policies nothing changes.

Comment: @harrymc Updated with  Windows Update Assistant

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Comment: If the problem was solved by installing a feature update, that implies, you had enabled a group policy to block feature updates from being installing.  Which begs the question what version of Windows 10 were you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to do the update via the
[Windows Update Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).